# In my child component , I want to get specific id details?

Tags: angular, parent-child

In my child component I want to get specific id details. but it's not working. I am able to pass an id in the URL, but its displaying all id details. Here is my code:

ne-policy.html (parent)

```html
<div class="pb-3 pl-3" *ngFor="let product of selectedItemsList">
    <h4 class="fw-500 fw-b">
        <a (click)="openCaseDetails(product.id)">{{ product.template_name }}</a>
    </h4>
    <p>{{ product.template_name }}</p>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
</div>
```

.ts:

```js
openCaseDetails(id: Number){
         this.router.navigate(['pipeline/cluster/policies/policy-details/', id])
        }
```

policy-details.ts

```js
GetProductDatabyID() {
    var value =  this.Route.url.substring(this.Route.url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    this.projectclosterservice.getNetworkList()
 
        .subscribe(

          data => {
            this.ProductData = data['1tool-gitlab-pipeline'];
            const x = this.ProductData.filter((r:any)=>r.id==value)
            if(x.length!=0){
              this.DisplayProductList = x;
              console.log(this.DisplayProductList);
            }
            
          },
          error => {
  
          });
     
        }
```

.html

```html
<div class="message-container" *ngFor="let product of DisplayProductList">
    <pre class="text-white">{{ product.template_yamlfile }}</pre>
</div>
```

routing:

```js
{
      path:'policies',
      component:NetworkPoliciesComponent,
      children: [
        {
           path: 'policy-details/:id', component: NetworkDetailsComponent 
        }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are able to get id in `GetProductDatabyID` method

Comment: have you initialized `DisplayProductList` as `DisplayProductList = this.ProductData`, How you have declared `DisplayProductList` in `policy-details.ts`

Answer (score 1):

I have modified my code in this way and it's working fine, But I am still looking for an answer where it shows particular id details and rest should disappear. That means, when I click on title, it should show only that particular title details, and rest should not show up. Here is my modified code:

policies.html

```html
<div class="pb-3 pl-3" *ngFor="let product of selectedItemsList">
    <h4 class="fw-500 fw-b">
        <a (click)="openCaseDetails(product.id)">{{ product.template_name }}</a>
        <angularpipeline-network-details *ngIf="iddetails == product.id"></angularpipeline-network-details>
    </h4>
</div>
```

policies.ts

```js
openCaseDetails(id: Number) {

    if (this.iddetails = id) {
      this.router.navigate(['pipeline/cluster/policies/policy-details/', id])
    } else {

    }
}
```

I have removed `router-outlet` and added child component selector. Hope this solution helps. I did not change anything in the `policies-details` component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
In policy-details.ts

```
displayProductList$: Observable<any> = of([]);

constructor(private _activatedroute:ActivatedRoute){}

GetProductDatabyID() {
    //var id =  this.Route.url.substring(this.Route.url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);// removable
    const id = this._activatedroute.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.displayProductList$ = this.projectclosterservice.getNetworkList()
    .pipe(
        pluck('1tool-gitlab-pipeline'),
        tap(gitLabData => this.ProductData = gitLabData),
        map(gitLabData => gitLabData.filter(item => item.id==id))
    );
}
```

In policy-details template

```
<div class="message-container" *ngFor="let product of displayProductList$ | async">
    <pre class="text-white">{{ product.template_yamlfile }}</pre>
</div>
```

Imports:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { tap, map, pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: Hi @Navnath jadhav, Thank you, I have imported your code, but its showing this error,
"property "filter" doesnt exist on type "unknown"

Comment: Trey replacing `map(gitLabData => gitLabData.filter(item => item.id==id))`   
  with     `map((gitLabData: any[]) => gitLabData.filter(item => item.id==id))`

Comment: Okay, I have tried Navnath Jadhav, Did not work, there must be something wrong from my side. The code that I posted above as an answer, its working fine. Thank you so much for your prompt reply.

Comment: Is your code working now? What changes you made?

Comment: not as expected, I have added my code below, those are my changes. I have removed router-outllet, and added policy-details selector in policy component by adding ngIf conditions, You can have a look at my code below.

Comment: If you share some sample code with me on https://stackblitz.com/ I can help you.

Comment: Yeah Sure, that would be great, How can I do that.?

Comment: Setup your code on https://stackblitz.com/.  or create a sample code here that could demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Appreciated. Please don't forget to mark the answer if it solved your issue

Comment: Once it is fixed, I will definitely do that, I will share my sample code on stackblitz.com